# Elapsed Months calculation not giving correct result for dates with current month and day but a different year

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to calculate months elapsed since a particular date, the function works fine albeit it gives me a one months difference (Less than one month) if I put a date of today with a different year of the past.

Say for all dates the function works well, except:

If it is "2014-03-06" (YYYY,MM,DD) today and I process a date as "2006-03-06" to the function, the result is one month shorter, however if I use the same date tomorrow, the result is just fine. WOnder where I am going wrong. Below is the code:

```
public static int months(String d) {

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1 = null;
        try {
            d1 = f.parse(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //   Date d2 = (getCurrentDate());
        Date d2 = getCurrentDate(); 
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(d1);
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(d2);
        int diff = 0;
        if (c2.after(c1)) {
            while (c2.after(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                if (c2.after(c1)) {
                    diff++;
                }
            }
        } else if (c2.before(c1)) {
            while (c2.before(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                if (c1.before(c2)) {
                    diff--;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(diff);
        return diff;
    }
```

#### Result: 95 months.

#### Ideally it should be 96 months.

Please dont consider the static nature of functions, I have isolated this code in a different project for test purpose.

This is the value of c1 and c2:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1141583400000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Kolkata",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2006,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=10,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=65,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0] and c2 is: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1394044200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Kolkata",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=10,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=65,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
95
```

My bad here is the getCurrentDate():

```
public static Date getCurrentDate() {
        String DateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"/*,
                current*/).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //  String DateStr = formattedDate;
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"/*, current*/).parse(DateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date dx = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        return dx;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try setting the calendar to non lenient mode by calling setLenient(false); at the beginning. Default is lenient. This could be the problem.

Comment: All I have to say is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: I will have to try that setLenient(false).

Comment: Or maybe there is something wrong with your algo. because you're only 1 month off.

Comment: Also, `Calendar` has time information contained with it as well which might be throwing it off...

Comment: @MadProgrammer definitely but for my next project, I have learnt my lessons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `getCurrentDate()` method. I have replaced with `new Date()` and output is `96` as you said.

Comment: what is your `getCurrentDate() method.`

Comment: how have you implemented getCurrentDate()? May be something is wrong there?

Comment: I have specified it in the code above, do you fine any discrepancy in there?

Comment: @user2822178 you have not posted the implemented method `getCurrentDate()`. You have just called that method in your code.

Comment: @user2822178 Basically, the time boundaries have changed enough to allow the `after` call to be `true` for each case...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, also I have added teh function now.

Answer (score 2):

The comparisons of the `Calendar` `after` and `before` also include the time information, this could be throwing of the calculation towards the end, cause the comparison to fail short...

Try adjusting the values to the day boundaries...for example...

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestMonths {

    public static final String TEST1 = "2006-03-06";
    public static final String TEST2 = "2014-03-06";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(months(TEST2));
    }

    public static Date getCurrentDate() throws ParseException {

        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(TEST1);

    }

    public static int months(String d) {

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d1 = f.parse(d);
            d2 = (getCurrentDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(d1);
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(d2);
        int diff = 0;
        if (c2.after(c1)) {
            System.out.println("After");
            setStartOfDay(c1);
            setEndOfDay(c2);
            while (c2.after(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                if (c2.after(c1)) {
                    diff++;
                }
            }
        } else if (c2.before(c1)) {
            System.out.println("Before");
            setStartOfDay(c2);
            setEndOfDay(c1);
            while (c2.before(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                if (c2.before(c1)) {
                    diff--;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(diff);
        return diff;
    }

    public static void setStartOfDay(Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    }

    public static void setEndOfDay(Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 99);
    }
}
```

ps- I also corrected the "before" branch (where `c2` is "before" `c1`) as there was a logic error...

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not always possible and desirable to add new dependencies to the project, but have you considered using JodaTime library for date/time calculations? It has much cleaner api, and it follows all calendar/timezone restricitions very strictly.

Here is example for your dates (date parsing from strings is omitted).

```
    DateTime from = new DateTime(2006, 3, 6, 0, 0); //2006-03-06
    DateTime to = new DateTime(2014, 3, 6, 0, 0);   //2014-03-06
    System.out.println(new Interval(from, to).toPeriod(PeriodType.months()));
```

It prints "P96M", that is, 96 months.

Note that this example uses default (system) timezone.

Comment: For the next project for sure, I have learnt a great lesson the hard way. But currently as it stands, I cannot.

Comment: Rahul, could you please explain what you mean by "complex"?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Date d2 = getCurrentDate();
```

to this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d2 =  now.getTime();
```

It returns 96 to me.

Edited---

If you're using your function getCurrentDate(), i suggest you replace it with this:

```
public static Date getCurrentDate() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d2 =  now.getTime();
    return d2
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [correct answer by Deinlandel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216466/642706) points out, this date-time work is much easier with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Here's my take on some example code.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime( "2006-03-06", timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeStop = new DateTime( "2014-03-06", timeZone );
int months = Months.monthsBetween( dateTimeStart, dateTimeStop ).getMonths();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeStart: " + dateTimeStart );
System.out.println( "dateTimeStop: " + dateTimeStop );
System.out.println( "months: " + months );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeStart: 2006-03-06T00:00:00.000+01:00
dateTimeStop: 2014-03-06T00:00:00.000+01:00
months: 96
```

Comment: I have moved very much far with the code, cant change to Joda time. However your valuable guidance is much much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2822178 Know that [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) has a new [`java.time` package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built-in, meant to supplant the old java.util.Date/Calendar classes. Those new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) but are re-architected. So you get the benefits of Joda-Time without having to add an external dependency. [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defines the new package.

Comment: thank you, I knew that however the state of project I am in right now, its very hard to change anything. For sure I will do it for the next time.